# React-native upgrade associated type errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I upgraded react-native

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.4",
```

to

```
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
```

I did ala everything react native upgrade helper documents

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.4&to=0.62.2

but I encountered these errors

```
"associated type descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByFloatLiteral.FloatLiteralType", referenced from:

"associated type descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral.IntegerLiteralType", referenced from:

"value witness table for Builtin.Int32", referenced from:
```

[image]

Comment: have you done a `pod install` ?
Also make sure you have clean your xcode project, and close and reopen it (some wild errors disappear with restarting xcode)

Comment: Yes, I did everything is clean npm cache, pod cache, and Xcode

Comment: Apparently they recommend here to not upgrade the *.xcodeproj file and follow this :   https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/13

Comment: Thank you Salim I tried but didn't

Comment: Merhabalar, ilk once {yourPoject}/ios dosyasina girin, daha sonra orda iki tur Xcode dosyasi goreceksiniz . 1.yourPoject.xcodeproj 2.yourPoject.xcworkspace.    siz 2. dosyasi xcode ile acip command+K basip daha sonra build alin, boylece sorun cozulecek.

Comment: Hi, the console clone you mentioned is unfortunately not the problem here, cache, and so on.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After upgrading to react-native 0.63.3 took the same error.

The root cause of this was my project only had objective-C files.

The solution is just to add an empty swift file under your project in xcode and all of your linking errors will be solved.

```
File -> New -> File

Select Swift File
```

Comment: Nice, worked a treat! For those wondering what to name the file, you can just give it the same name as the project folder but it can be anything